# Virtual host document root doesn't work

Tags: apache2, subdomain, xampp, virtualhost

I created an A record for my `subdomain.example.com` which points `x.x.x.x`.
So my subdomain points the x.x.x.x IP address.

Also I want my subdomain to point a sub-directory. So, on `x.x.x.x`, I added these lines to `httpd.vhosts.conf`. This machine runs on xampp.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/subdomain
ServerName subdomain.example.com
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/subdomain>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But `subdomain.example.com` points `x.x.x.x` not `x.x.x.x/subdomain`. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/sections.html#mergin

Due to the merging order, some of the directives may override others. I found that `<location>` directive didn't let my `<virtualhost>` work properly.